# Increase height of the textfield in ExtJS using %

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, extjs

`.ext-ie .x-small-editor .x-form-text {
height:29px !important; //works
height:50% !important; //not works
}`

The above code works fine in ie but its not accepting %
similarly

`.x-grid3-col .x-form-field{
height:50px !important;
}`

This code works in Firefox/chrome but again not allowing %

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear about what exactly is being asked?

Comment: need increase the height of the textfield ex: new ext.form.texfield